# What permissions are necessary for an IAM role to have aws console access to dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I created a user with following permission. When I login as this user, I don't see any tables under DynamoDB. Do I need to add any additional permissions.

```
AWSDataPipeline_FullAccess
AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess
AmazonSNSReadOnlyAccess
IAMReadOnlyAccess
AWSLambdaReadOnlyAccess
CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess
```

Comment: Did you create a **Role** or a **User**? You login to the console as a User, so the permissions should be assigned to the User. Or did you use the **Switch Role** function in the console? Feel free to edit your question to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me!

Here's what I did:

- Created a table in DynamoDB using an existing user
- Create a new IAM User in IAM with the `AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess` standard policy
- Logged in as the new User, went to the DynamoDB console

I could view the list of tables and the content of tables

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the region was an issue. After I switched to the right region, the tables started showing. Thanks all.